# Removing certain text and line breaks then adding a line break after X count of commas PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running a script to pull information from a 'show' command on a Cisco that I want to put in to a MYSQL database and have this automated, so I just look at the 'final data' output. As an FYI I cannot use 'SNMPget' as the devices don't have OID's for this output :

So the flow of the information from the show command is like such:

```
ABC DEF GHI JKL
      TY123 AB456 RT789
```

So I want to initially format it to look like:

```
ABC DEF GHI JKL 123 456 789
```

So I am removing the linebreaks and removing specific text before the numbers.

Then I want to be able to, replace the whitespace with commas, then line break after the first sequence is complete so in this example after the amount of commas is done for a sequence it starts a new line.

So it looks like:

```
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,123,456,789,
MNO,PQR,STU,VWX,987,654,321,
```

I've tried to play around using a `str_replace()` and `split` command sets but I can't seem to get it to do what I want to do.

Could someone help with an example that would achieve the above please?

Comment: Do you want to do this using MySQL or PHP?

Comment: By PHP i think. The end result will be having it go in to a MySQL database but i'd have assumed PHP has to do the formatting first?

Comment: Can do this in MySQL, but will be easier using PHP

Comment: What does the `MNO` line and next line look like in relation to the one you show in the original text?

Comment: So the rules are what exactly? Remove all line breaks, replace all spaces with commas, and finally, any strings that are letters prepended to numbers should be numeric only, then line break after this, right?

Comment: Yeah, Remove all line breaks, replace all spaces with commas and remove specific words from the string i.e the actual issue is 'uptime 1s' so i'd want to remove 'uptime', the 's' is fine - otherwise i'd have a column full of just the word 'uptime' and yes then line break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a function which :

1. Explodes your string on every space then trims each value
2. Checks if the value has letters then numbers
3. If 2 is false, then output your value then `,`
4. If 2 is true, then get the numbers only, output them then `,`

Then you have to use this function on each of your input strings, store them in an array and implode it with a new line :

```
$string1 = 'ABC DEF GHI JKL
      TY123 AB456 RT789';
$string2 = 'MNO PQR STU VWX
      TY987 AB654 RT321';

$output_array = array();
$output = '';
$output_array[] = transformString($string1);
$output_array[] = transformString($string2);
$output = implode("\n", $output_array);

var_dump($output);

function transformString($string) {
    $return = '';
    $array = explode(' ', $string);
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $value = trim($value);
        if ($value == '')
            continue;
        preg_match('#^[A-Z]+([0-9]+)$#', $value, $matches);
        if (empty($matches)) {
            $return .= $value . ',';
        } else {
            $return .= $matches[1] . ',';
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Output :

```
string 'ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,123,456,789,
MNO,PQR,STU,VWX,987,654,321,' (length=57)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace every space, new line and letters before numbers into a comma char. A pair of regexps can do the job:

```
$txt = "ABC DEF GHI JKL
      TY123 AB456 RT789";
$txt = preg_replace('#[ \n]+#i', ',', $txt);
$txt = preg_replace('#,[a-z]+([0-9]+)#i', ',\\1', $txt);
echo $txt;
```

Output: ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,123,456,789

http://ideone.com/hrfIFJ